# Automatically go to end of buffer after opening a file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to tell Emacs to automatically scroll to the end of the file upon opening it?

Note that I don't need this for every file, just for some of them. Ideally, I'd like to be able to set this behavior for all files in certain type/mode. It gets a bit annoying having to type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `end-of-buffer` every time right after opening a file.

Comment: FYI: Use of `M->` is *very basic*. Nothing wrong with asking such a question or not knowing about `M->` and using `M-x end-of-buffer` instead. But you will help yourself by dipping into the Emacs manual. `M->` is right up front, in node `Basic` > `Moving Point`. You can find it by `C-h r` (to access the manual) followed by `i end-of-buffer` (or `i end TAB` and then choose `end-of-buffer`). (`i` is your friend - it looks things up in the index.) HTH.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you can use `M->` to do that quickly.

To do it automatically with certain files, you can use a hook.

`(add-hook 'your-mode-hook 'end-of-buffer)`

Answer (score 3):

A crude method for doing so from the command line:

```
emacs +$(wc -l FILE_NAME)
```

Comment: cool.  I often look at the same log file, always from the end.  Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget help command `C-h w` which reveals associated key-binding if you know the command name.

`C-h w` type `end-of-buffer` (use `TAB` here for less typing) `RET`

In the message area you can see the following,

```
 end-of-buffer is on <C-end>, M->, <menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <end-of-buf>
```